# Is it bidah to make salutations upon prophet Muhammad at any time?

Tags: salat, dua, bidah

I heard that Prophet Muhammad said that it’s good to send blessings upon him at fajr and Maghrib, But instead I do at all times (Fajr, Dhuhr, Asr, Maghrib, and Isha), Is this bidah???

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: No, if your intention is purely just to give salutation and not doing any specific deed (cmiiw). And Allah knows best.